# Screenshot to cloud in linux

Tags: linux, screenshot, cloud

Is there a program for linux that takes a screenshot, uploads it to the cloud and generates a link to share with friends?

Meaning, does all that seamlessly, without having to save it to a file and upload it to dropbox, for example.

Comment: write a script! must be very easy.

Comment: @casey_miller If it's so easy, why not write one for the OP? I'm sure he'd appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vzXr.jpg
- http://sirupsen.com/a-simple-imgur-bash-screenshot-utility/

Comment: Thank you @JohannesM . This is exactly what I was looking for. I just wish imgur's upload API wasn't so slow.